# Error enabling EventDate 1.0 module on Orchard 1.6 CMS

Tags: asp.net, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

I have been trying to install and enable EventDate 1.0 module on Orchard 1.6, but it is installing fine but can not enable, it is throwing server error below.

*Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.*

Any advise would be great

Comment: It would be great to have the actual stack trace, but this module is probably incompatible with 1.6. Just delete its folder under Modules.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. is that any other event module or any other way we could do Event Calendar on Orchard 1.6? I tried with other but it also having same error.

Comment: I don't know. Again, it would help to have the actual stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid EventDate and Timetables require the use of RoutePart, which is no longer used since...1.4 I believe. You would have to go through and change all references of RoutePart to AutoRoute. I had a quick look through and I don't think it is worth the time or effort, better to create your own module. I don't think there are any modules that deal with events like what you probably have in mind.

Sorry!